# Change the tempo\bpm of mp3 file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c

I am looking for a way to change the bpm\tempo of mp3 file(that also convert already to mp3).

its also can be done with c library that i will add to my project.

Comment: Maybe look in to the tech used here?  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RGpkNPbSa2Q ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two methods for changing the perceived tempo of audio. One method is to simply alter the playback speed. This is easy to do with PCM audio, but will require you to decode the MP3. It might be possible to alter the sample rate (effectively the same thing) in the compressed domain (i.e. in the MP3 file itself), but I don't know how to do that. The big drawback with this approach is *all* the pitches in the audio change, too. This can make vocals sound unnatural, for instance.

Another approach is to apply a pitch-invariant speed change. This is a far more complex operation, and there are many proprietary algorithms and research papers addressing it. The pitch-synchronous overlap add (PSOLA) technique is one that works well. You can also look at what Audacity (an open-source audio editor) does. Since you are on iOS, Apple's audio framework might also provide some support for this. Look for AUPitch in the iOS documentation.